# Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Tags: linux, blackberry, titanium, blackberry-simulator

sorry for my English...I try to talk through a translator.

I'm starting make mobile apps with Titanium Studio 3.1.3 and I have problems with my Blackberry simulator and Linux operating systems .

At first , in the section on "Get Started" in the " Dashboard" of Titanium Studio, I get Blackberry marked in red. I have defined the settings in the following order :

> - Blackberry NDK Home: "/home/.../SDKs/Blackberry/bbndk"
> - Blackberry Debug Token: "/home/.../.rim/debugtoken1.bar"
> - Device IP: "192.168.221.128" (the IP is listed in the simulator, below left outside the emulator screen, where the PinCode etc.)
> - Simulator IP: "169.254.0.1" (IP is the blackberry emulated system within security / development options)
> - Device Password (The password for the Blackberry system emulator)
> - Keystore Password (The password / .rim/debugtoken1.bar)

With the above options , Blackberry is marked in red , however, if I can write applications compatible with blackberry .

The real problem I have at the time you want to generate the aplicación.bar and emulate . I tried from the interface of titanium studio or linux command line, but the result was the same for both.

> "[DEBUG] Copying
>   /.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/Resources/blackberry =>
>   /.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/build/blackberry/assets [DEBUG]
>   Copying /.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/Resources/blackberry/map =>
>   /.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/build/blackberry/assets/map [INFO]
>   No Titanium Modules required, continuing [Command] :source
>   /home/.../SDKs/Blackberry/bbndk/bbndk-env_10_2_0_1155.sh &&
>   blackberry-nativepackager -package
>   "/.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/build/blackberry/x86/o-g/app.bar"
>   bar-descriptor.xml -e
>   "/.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/build/blackberry/x86/o-g/app"
>   "app" -buildID 1 assets framework -devMode Error: Command failed:
>   /bin/sh: 1: source: not found" /bin/sh: 1: source: not found [Command]
>   :source /home/.../SDKs/Blackberry/bbndk/bbndk-env_10_2_0_1155.sh &&
>   blackberry-deploy -installApp -launchApp -device 192.168.221.128
>   -package "/.../Titanium_Studio_Workspace/app/build/blackberry/x86/o-g/app.bar"
>   Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

At first , I can assume that the "source" command does not exist in my Linux , however when I copy the command and execute it manually, this command exists and want to find the file " bar - descriptor.xml " . If I move it manually with the command "cd " to the directory where " bar - descriptor.xml " and run the command again , I get the following result :

> "Error: Attribute Entry- Point : file can not be found in the list of
>   packaged files: app "

I guess now is waiting for the right file and compiled as app.bar not finished, is because they don't compile .